# stylesheet in other directory with noscript

Tags: html, css, noscript

I am creating a website in HTML, and I face a problem.

I have a CSS folder, and I want to be able to access it from every directory

root:

```
/css  
   - /skel-noscript.css"    
   - /skel-noscript.css"
 
/js
   - init.js
   - skel.min.js
   - skel-panel.min.js
   - html5shiv.js

/Downloads
   -/Download.html
 
/Downloads.html

/index.html
```

...

Now I have trouble when I try to access the stylesheets in `Downloads/Download.html`

my `<head>` code:

```
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
</head>
```

When I use this code, the stylesheets don't work.
when I delete the `<noscript>` around the links to the stylesheets, they do work, but my website is totally messed up.

[image]

What is happening?
When I  use this code in the root directory, it works fine

Comment: One of the following should happend in order to the noscript tag be executed:

script type on the page is unsupported 
or scripting is currently turned off in the browser.

Comment: @Melvinr when i do so, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

css files are not being added from  tags in this case,  is for browsers that don't support js or if js is off. 
go to the "init.js" file(one that u attached just before the  tag) in your js folder and check it... css  is being added from their so change directory paths for css from there.
regards

Comment: Yeah, i can't really check it because it was a template i downloaded and it's all minified. i don't use it anymore... but i did fix it by removing these js files and including the css without the noscript tags. still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you turning off the javascript when testing this? `<noscript>` is only activated when the visitor has no scripting enabled. If you want to be able to link the css files always you have to get rid of the  tag.

Comment: i start debugging, stylesheet doesn't work. i turn off javascript, and again, the stylesheet doesn't work. when i turn javascript back on, the site is messed up like on the picture. and if i reload the page, this starts again from the beginning. weird???

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a file something like header.phtml and call all the files you need to render the template.

```
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <noscript>
        <link href"<?= $this->getCssPath(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type=text/css />
    </noscript>
</head>
```

and greate a file where you create a class something like

```
<?php class MyTemplate {

public function getCssPath() {

return 'css/skel-noscript.css';
       }

}
```

Comment: i'm pretty new to html. i don't understand how i could do this. is there any documentation?

Comment: so this is going to be the .phtml file if i understand it right? btw i did a test, and moved the /css and /js folders under /downloads. it worked perfect. so it is something with the location of the files i guess. maybe i can't get to the root directory by using: `../css/style.css`

Comment: so how to fix it? does this solution fix it?